# Having problem with login with Flutter Firebase email and password authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have problems with the Flutter code for the Firebase email/password sign-in.
When email address and password are correct, nothing happens.
When email address or password are not correct the `"Error "+errMsg.toString()` is generated.
In console I read:

> W/System  (21892): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value
> was null. D/FirebaseAuth(21892): Notifying id token listeners about
> user ( R6GCSXPvbUgbu4uQXdLYtXD1Lyo1 ).

Here is the code:

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void loginAndAuthenticateUser(BuildContext context) async{
    final User firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailTextEditingController.text,
        password: passwordTextEditingController.text)
        .catchError((errMsg) {
      displayToastMessage("Error " + errMsg.toString(), context);
    })).user;

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot snap){
        if (snap.value == null){
          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
          displayToastMessage("You are logged in.", context);
        }
        else{
          _firebaseAuth.signOut();
          displayToastMessage("User not found.", context);
        }
      });
    }
    else{
      displayToastMessage("Error occurred.", context);
    }
  }

  displayToastMessage(String message, BuildContext context) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: message);
  }
```

Comment: Run the `flutter doctor -v` command and post the output

Comment: it says "No issues found"

Comment: Are you running the app on an `Emulator` ?

Comment: Yes, Android Emulator

Comment: Test it with your device to see what you will get

Comment: When trying to create APK the Flutter says:  Note: D:\Programiranje\Flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.5.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: Flutter says what ?

Comment: Which dependencies are you using in your `pubspec.yaml` ?

Comment: cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
  firebase_database: ^4.4.0
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the best thing that I know to do is do a "try" "except" statement, I have definitely come across this problem before and wish it was easier to manage.

Comment: Thank you man. I solved it with you hint.